# what should be the design approach to use different business error code in micro service base application

Tags: java, csv, spring-boot, enums

In my application, there are multiple micro-services which are communicating through the queue. Each service can throw a business/fatal exception. These business errors are currently stored as an excel, in the system. As for each field, we can get different type of errors, hence different error codes with different severity (there are other fields too in the excel sheet for the error).

Now, we want to redesign this thing. Hence we were thinking to maintain an enum with a different business error code which would be used by the other services.

My concern is, having more than a hundred entries in an ENUM, will it be a clean and fast approach as each error code is gonna have 3-4 attributes.

Can someone suggest an alternate approach to this?

Comment: If your errors could be grouped somehow you could create several enums or several nested enums.

Comment: What about using a properties file ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403172/best-practice-for-storage-and-retrieval-of-error-messages